# Web Api 2 set route to ApiController method dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I would like to set the route to a method within an ApiController dynamically. The below shows my TokenController:

```
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/token/{grantType}")]
    [RequireHttps]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string grantType)
    {}
}
```

I am thinking of using dependency injection as follows:

```
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    public TokenController(ITokenService tokenService)
    {   
        //configure route "api/token/{grantType}" using tokenService?
    }

    [Route("api/token/{grantType}")]
    [RequireHttps]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string grantType)
    {}
}
```

Or do I need to do this in **App_Start** using the `HttpConfiguration` object?

How would I do this?

Comment: Why can't you just call `tokenService` from inside your route? Your question is a little unclear.

Comment: I want to configure the route to the Post method - I want to change  [Route("api/token/{grantType}")]. I don't think one can do that from within the method.

Comment: Change it in what way though? Do you mean you want to change for example `api/token/{grantType}` to something like `api/token/anotherurl/{grantType}`? This information is important, you need to make your question clear enough for people to answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to set the route api/token/{grantType} to api/somethingelse/{grantType} or whatever at runtime.

Comment: Can you explain the use case?

Comment: The idea is to have the functionality reused in another web api. My TokenController has a method that returns a token, which is provided by a TokenService. So in another web api project I will create a token service by implementing ITokenService. I then want to somehow specify the route to the method/endpoint that returns the token.

Comment: I'm confused, if you have *another* web API project then you would in theory have a different controller and therefore a different route? Sorry but I just can't seem to understand what it is you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer. I will configure the endpoint route with `HttpConfiguration`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{   
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                            name: "API TokenEndpoint",
                            routeTemplate: "services/newtoken/{grantType}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Token" action="Post"},
                            constraints: null);
        }   
}
```